# rsync taking 100% of CPU and hours to complete

Tags: backup, rsync

So I have a pretty simple backup script that runs as a cron job every night and it is:

```
rsync -azhv /company/shared_files/ /mnt/ext_drive/backups/shared_files/company_share_backup_"`date +\%Y-\%m-\%d`"
```

And previously the size of the backup was around 20 gigs and it ran in around ten minutes but as of two days ago it is 80 gigs and it takes 6+ hours to run. What could have gone wonky?

My general procedure is to keep each backup for 7 days and then keep the backup from Sunday each week to save space so ideally I would like to do a separate rsync for each day as opposed to doing rsync in its more natural fashion of just updating the files in a backup that have changed.

### Additional Details

I'm running Debian Wheezy with a 2TB hard drive and 16G of memory and transferring these files from my Debian server to a WD My Passport Ultra with 2TB.

Comment: Perhaps a folder with many small files appeared?

Comment: Haha I just learned that that is precisely what happened. Does that seem like a reasonable increase in time for 60G of small files? And if so do you know anything I can do to increase speed?

Comment: @clifgray - It's hard to say if that's a reasonable increase without knowing a lot more about the situation, but I think it's reasonable to say that adding a lot of small files won't do anything good for performance.

Comment: One option is to use different backups for small files vs the rest. For example a tar backup for all files <= 128K and rsync backup for anything larger.

Comment: Look at rsnapshot if you have time. Very useful, very simple. https://rsnapshot.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few things you can do there. You don't need the `-z` flag to rsync for a local copy. Compression is not used for transfers that aren't remote.

You can optimize the rsync a bit better for small files and the type of changes with other options like `-W` (to transfer whole files without the prescan).

Also, shouldn't you be deleting files on the destination?

More details on the actual OS you're using, the disk capabilities and the backup target could help focus the solution a bit better.

Comment: Great thanks for the tips. I added some details, let me know if any more would be helpful. Why would I be deleting files on the destination?

Comment: I was having this problem too, on FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE, this answer is still helpful 4 years later.  Was using the -z flag, will omit and add -w.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I guess your file transfer was not limited by `rsync` but the target device. The reason it first seemed to go fast is that you probably have lots of RAM and you have big values in `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_ratio` and `/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_ratio`. This allows writing to happen from source to RAM for the progress you see but when the RAM cache is full and the files actually need to be written on the disk you see the process slowing down.

If this happens in more recent target disk (e.g. new Seagate 4+ TB disks) you may have [SMR HDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shingled_magnetic_recording) target device. For example, Seagate 4 TB and 6 TB SMR HDDs are fast only for the first 20 GB you write because drive has internal PMR cache area and much slower SMR area and this is all handled internally (this is so called "drive managed" setup). After the cache is full, the write performance drops from 160 MB/s to around 25 MB/s for sequential writing and **from 80-160 MB/s to 1 MB/s** for random file writes. This is actual *hardware performance* of the device and there're no special tricks that can help with it. The only real "fix" is to wait for the device to complete the task. Once the storage device is left powered on for long enough time (for Seagate SMR devices this seems to be around half an hour) the internal cache will be flushed to slower permanent area and after that the device is fast again for the next ~20 GB burst. If you only write up to 20 GB in a single burst (in practice within 30 min), you'll never experience this problem.

Unfortunately, most hardware vendors do not publicly disclose the amount of fast cache and all the spec numbers *always* refer to fast cache area only. After the fast cache is full, the performance of the device is usually much much lower. This happens with SSD devices, too. For example, Samsung EVO series is known to manifest similar behavior even though the hardware is otherwise very good. In case of Samsung EVO, the drop is not 100x like in SMR drives but more like 2-3x slower.

Comment: Do you have a source for the drop from 80-160 MB/s to 1Mb/s or is it just a ballpark estimation?

Comment: Source is actual testing with `fio` on my own hardware (4 Seagate HDD drives). Yes, the performance drop is truly that bad but to get that bad results, you have to write data in random order. SMR drives are only good with big sequential writes or so little activity that the PMR cache area can be written to SMR areas during idle periods. (I just checked that two of the drives had type `ST4000DM004-2CV104` and `ST6000DM003-2CY186`.)

Answer (score 2):

Please be sure you're not on a hacked machine, a lot of users (me included) have found bitcoin miners hiding behind rsync or other processes.
To check:

- look at users cron jobs: `# crontab -l -u alex`
- Delete folders listed in found malicious cron jobs
- Delete hidden folders in /tmp
- Delete **unknown** keys in /home/USER/.ssh/authorized_keys or worse /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
- install ClamAv and setup weekly scan: [Link](https://www.clamav.net/documents/installing-clamav)
- Uknown users: `lslogins`
- [/etc/ssh/sshd_config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config) should allow only one, non root user for SSH: `AllowUsers me mom dad`
- use more robust passwords and log in with public key

Other reports https://askubuntu.com/questions/1115770/crond64-tsm-virus-in-ubuntu

Comment: Note that if it turns out that your machine has been hacked, the only *real* solution is to reinstall the whole operating system from known good media. The attacker may have installed root kit that you're not aware of and and no matter what you do within the running operating system it cannot be removed. Of course, create backup of your *data* before wiping the system for reinstall.

Comment: Of course, but this is not always possible or the best solution. In this case the hacked account was only a non root user without sudo privileges

Comment: If the attacker was competent, he or she would have used local root exploit to get temporary root and install a root kit. If it was just some automated script looking for free CPU time and got a normal user account, I agree that you're probably okay without full reinstall. The problem is, if the attacker is really good, both cases look the same for the system admin. It really comes down to the risk level you're willing to accept.

Comment: I agree, indeed this was a testing machine with no sensitive data